# How to create gif from list of images in c using imagemagick

Tags: c, imagemagick, gif, animated-gif

How can I make .gif file from list of images (frames) on the computer drive using C? (It's better if it's using ImageMagick Library)

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Why not just do it in the Terminal with **ImageMagick** `magick -delay 80 frame*.png animated.gif`

Comment: I have project to build a gif maker, and I want to add an option to export the project as gif

Comment: Magshimist?????

Comment: @Irkl1_ no, I'm a Machshilist .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ImageMagick, you would read each frame into the stack, and then write a GIF with an adjoin option.

```c
MagickWand * wand;
wand = NewMagickWand();
MagickReadImage(wand, "frame_one.png");
MagickReadImage(wand, "frame_two.png");
MagickReadImage(wand, "frame_three.png");
MagickWriteImages(wand, "output.gif", MagickTrue);
```

Be sure to invoke `MagickWandGenesis()` before working with ImageMagick library, and `MagickWandTerminus()` at the end of the application. Also check which version of ImageMagick you wish to compile with:

- `#include <wand/MagickWand.h>` for ImageMagick-6
- `#include <MagickWand/MagickWand.h>` for ImageMagick-7 (preferred)

Comment: Thank you! It works, but do you know how can I add duration for each frame in the gif?
For Example "frame_one.png" is 1000 ms, "frame_two.png" is 300 ms...

Comment: You would add `MagickSetImageDelay(MagickWand *wand, size_t delay)` after reading each frame, or use image-iterators to walk across the image stack.

Comment: Do you know how can I use the library on Visual Studio?